# How to convert an array of objects to string and insert into sql using php?

Tags: php, arrays

Currently I've got a list of array of sizes. I want the size to have quantity stock for each sizes.
Each object(of size and stock) will be inside an array and insert into sql.

```
class Item
        {
            public $size;
            public $stock;
        }
        $sizeArr = array("S", "M", "L", "XL");
        $arrObject = [];
        foreach ($sizeArr as $i) {
            $tempItem = new Item();
            $tempItem->size = $i;
            $tempItem->stock = 0;
            serialize($tempItem);
            array_push($arrObject,$tempItem);
        }

        echo implode(" ",$arrObject); //Object of class Item could not be converted to string
        //$sql = "INSERT INTO itemstock (itemName, description ,imgLinkArr, sizingAndStock, createddate) VALUES ('$itemname', '$textToStore', '$imageuri', '$sizing', '$date');";
        //mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Here, I got an error saying `Object of class Item could not be converted to string`. How can I convert the array of objects to string and insert to SQL?

Comment: you might think about converting it to JSON using [json_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: You should look into normalizing your database design, holding data as some form of string to represent information about an item can be difficult to search for in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

In here you are converting an object of class into the string. First, you need to convert that object into an array and then convert it into the string. See the following example :

```
<?php
class Item
    {
        public $size;
        public $stock;
    }
    $sizeArr = array("S", "M", "L", "XL");
    $arrObject = [];
    foreach ($sizeArr as $i) {
        $tempItem = new Item();
        $tempItem->size = $i;
        $tempItem->stock = 0;
        serialize($tempItem);
        $tempItemArray = (array) $tempItem;
        array_push($arrObject,$tempItemArray);
    }

    $final_val = '';
    foreach($arrObject as $ao) {
        $final_val .= implode(" ",$ao).",";
    }
    echo $final_val;
?>
```